# angular 5 validation form control update with required

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular 5. And How do I add required validation to an existing form control??

```
this.formSearch.get('name').clearValidators();
this.formSearch.get('name').updateValueAndValidity();
```

Comment: Try `this.myform.get('field').setValidators([Validators.required]);` and then call `this.myform.get('field').updateValueAndValidity();`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Angular comes with a small set of pre-built validators to match the ones we can define via standard HTML5 `attributes`, `namely required`, `minlegth`, `maxlength` and `pattern` which we can access from the Validators module.

The first parameter of a `FormControl` constructor is the initial value of the control, we’ll leave that as empty string. The second parameter contains either a single validator if we only want to apply one, or a list of validators if we want to apply multiple validators to a single control.

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

class ModelFormComponent implements OnInit {
  myform: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    myform = new FormGroup({
        name: new FormGroup({
            firstName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
            lastName: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        }),
        email: new FormControl('', [ 
            Validators.required,
            Validators.pattern("[^ @]*@[^ @]*") 
        ]),
        password: new FormControl('', [
            Validators.minLength(8), 
            Validators.required
        ]),
        language: new FormControl() 
    });
  }
}
```

1. We add a single required validator to mark this control as required.
2. We can also provide an array of validators.
3. We specify a pattern validator which checks whether the email contains a @ character.
4. The minlength validator checks to see if the password is a minimum of 8 characters long.
5. We don’t add any validators to the language select box.

**IN YOUR SCENARIO**
You can use something like this

```
this.formSearch.controls["name"].setValidators([Validators.required]‌​,[Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(30)]);
```

Here you simply pass the FormControl an array of validators. And this will reset any existing validators you added when you created the FormControl.

Additionally,

1. Set a validator for a control in the FormGroup: `this.formSearch.controls['name'].setValidators([Validators.required])`
2. Remove the validator from the control in the FormGroup: 
   `this.formSearch.controls['name'].clearValidators()`
3. Update the FormGroup once you have run either of the above lines. `this.formSearch.controls['name'].updateValueAndValidity()`

Comment: Invoke `updateValueAndValidity` is very important and really often it's omitted

Comment: @kris_IV can you please elaborate? My form is behaving as required even without invoking updateValueAndValidity after I clear and set validity on a form control.